# Why would the collection be missing from NFT metadata?

Tags: web3.js, metaplex, solscan

I am trying to pull the collection info for some NFTs and getting different metadata back than what is on solscan. Here is my sample code using something from the Genopet Cracked Egg collection.

```
const { Connection, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Metaplex } = require('@metaplex-foundation/js');

(async () => {
    const metaplex = new Metaplex(new Connection('https://rpc.helius.xyz/?api-key=foobar'));
    const mintAddress = new PublicKey("FMK7JqQkbqHyKM3gV5o8GznbquzQqaGwSMX6KPhFtD5r");

    const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(nft, null, 2));
})();
```

It returns this result which gives the collection name and family in `json` but the `collection` attribute is null.

```
{
  "model": "nft",
  "updateAuthorityAddress": "GenoS3ck8xbDvYEZ8RxMG3Ln2qcyoAN8CTeZuaWgAoEA",
  "json": {
    "name": "Cracked Genopet Egg #2572",
    "symbol": "CRACKED",
    "description": "This egg has cracked and can no longer be hatched into a Genopet.",
    "seller_fee_basis_points": 500,
    "image": "https://arweave.net/h9fUMsvnWV8X3DOHz_fMwLoYCacL5AQYAHOM5sswXqA",
    "external_url": "https://genopets.me",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "display_type": "number",
        "trait_type": "sequence",
        "value": 2572
      }
    ],
    "collection": {
      "name": "Genopet Eggs",
      "family": "Genopets"
    },
    "properties": {
      "category": "image",
      "files": [
        {
          "uri": "https://arweave.net/h9fUMsvnWV8X3DOHz_fMwLoYCacL5AQYAHOM5sswXqA",
          "type": "image/png"
        }
      ],
      "creators": [
        {
          "address": "GenoS3ck8xbDvYEZ8RxMG3Ln2qcyoAN8CTeZuaWgAoEA",
          "share": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "jsonLoaded": true,
  "name": "Cracked Genopet Egg #2572",
  "symbol": "CRACKED",
  "uri": "https://arweave.net/bwuxDCy0X5yl3Vbtc_mtcTZWwSsNHaaJ-Z-Jg3F7pF0",
  "isMutable": true,
  "primarySaleHappened": true,
  "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 500,
  "editionNonce": 254,
  "creators": [
    {
      "address": "GenoS3ck8xbDvYEZ8RxMG3Ln2qcyoAN8CTeZuaWgAoEA",
      "verified": true,
      "share": 100
    }
  ],
  "tokenStandard": null,
  "collection": null,
  "collectionDetails": null,
  "uses": null,
  "programmableConfig": null,
  "address": "FMK7JqQkbqHyKM3gV5o8GznbquzQqaGwSMX6KPhFtD5r",
  "metadataAddress": "EsTsvN1fQz9V6oro1vW1fTA6XfeC9bRg4sRpKZ9QeuMe",
  "mint": {
    "model": "mint",
    "address": "FMK7JqQkbqHyKM3gV5o8GznbquzQqaGwSMX6KPhFtD5r",
    "mintAuthorityAddress": "BTp82p6baoBhLfVt4zkCZfJdgnztLTTQkwuyDxbw1zK",
    "freezeAuthorityAddress": "BTp82p6baoBhLfVt4zkCZfJdgnztLTTQkwuyDxbw1zK",
    "decimals": 0,
    "supply": {
      "basisPoints": "01",
      "currency": {
        "symbol": "CRACKED",
        "decimals": 0,
        "namespace": "spl-token"
      }
    },
    "isWrappedSol": false,
    "currency": {
      "symbol": "CRACKED",
      "decimals": 0,
      "namespace": "spl-token"
    }
  },
  "edition": {
    "model": "nftEdition",
    "isOriginal": true,
    "address": "BTp82p6baoBhLfVt4zkCZfJdgnztLTTQkwuyDxbw1zK",
    "supply": "00",
    "maxSupply": "00"
  }
}
```

Looking at the same [FMK7JqQkbqHyKM3gV5o8GznbquzQqaGwSMX6KPhFtD5r](https://solscan.io/token/FMK7JqQkbqHyKM3gV5o8GznbquzQqaGwSMX6KPhFtD5r#metadata) token in solscan I can see `collection.key` is populated as I would expect.

```
"collection": {
    "verified": 78
    "key": "BuL27W2awQ3ETiSAgWhQbPthrTR9kQwJB9JtFJtb6DnP"
}
```

How can I get that `collection.key` in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The very interesting thing here is

"verified": 78

This should normally set to be either 1 or 0 (Boolean style). The is most likely why the js sdk does not see it as verified: it should be verified:1